# LCD in CircuitPython flashing on then off

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm trying to get an LCD display (1602 via I2C from pi pico W) to work, and my code is as follows:

```
import busio
import time
from adafruit_character_lcd import character_lcd_i2c

i2c = busio.I2C(board.GP15, board.GP14)

lcd = character_lcd_i2c.Character_LCD_I2C(i2c, 16, 2, address=0x3f)

lcd.clear()
lcd.home()
lcd.backlight = True
lcd.message = "Hello, World!"
time.sleep(2)
```

But when I run it, the screen flashes on for a second and doesn't show any text before shutting off. The I2C interface works after i manually set the address so I have no idea why its not working. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are different controllers for the I2C bus out there. The adafruit library is developed for the MCP23008, that is the chip they sell themselves. It has a default address of 0x20. Other chips use different default addresses.

Since you had to change the address to 0x3f I assume that you have a different chip. In my adapter there is a PCF8574 with a default address of 0x27.
As stated in https://lastminuteengineers.com/i2c-lcd-arduino-tutorial/ there are different manufacturers for the PCF8574, there is one from NXP that has a default address of 0x3f. So chances are good that you have one of those.

So you need a different library to communicate with your display.
For the PCF8574 I found this on Github: https://github.com/mrkaleArduinoLib/LiquidCrystal_I2C .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with CircuitPython, but found a solution. Download https://github.com/dhalbert/CircuitPython_LCD library and run this code (**note** *, you need to change **scl** and **sda** to your setup*):

```
import board
import busio

from lcd.lcd import LCD
from lcd.i2c_pcf8574_interface import I2CPCF8574Interface
from lcd.lcd import CursorMode

print("initialising i2c and looking for address")
i2c = busio.I2C(scl=board.GP15, sda=board.GP14)
i2c.try_lock()
address = i2c.scan()[0]
print(f"found address of i2c '{address}'")

i2c.unlock()
lcd = LCD(I2CPCF8574Interface(i2c, address), num_rows=2, num_cols=16)
print("debug: lcd initialised")

lcd.clear()
print("debug: clearing screen")

message = "Hello World!"
lcd.print(message)
print(f"debug: lcd printed '{message}'")
```

If the screen is on and you don't see any characters, then you need to adjust your contrast with phillips head screwdriver, found it [here](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?p=904951#p904951)